# Can't make a basic OR statement work correctly

Tags: php

In my PHP function, I want to `return` if the user is **not** a moderator **OR** if the user is not post author etc. See the following basic statement:

```
$mod = false;
$status = 'pending';
$currentuser = 22;
$author = 22;


if ( (!$mod) || ( ($status != 'pending') && ($currentuser != $author) )  ) {
        return;
}
```

So, in this example, the function should not return because `$currentuser` is `$author` and `$status` matches.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should explain better what you mean with "etc". The way I understand it, all you need is `||` instead of `&&` everywhere and far fewer parentheses. But that would be too easy, wouldn't it.

Comment: I think you want to use another && instead

Answer (score 2):

`(!$mod)` is true. The `if` condition is evaluated to true

You end up having:

```
if ( true || anotherCondition  ) {
    return;
}
```

It doesn't matter what the other condition is in this case. It evaluates to `true`

Your code is pretty close to what you need.

```
if ( (!$mod) && ($status != 'pending') && ($currentuser != $author) ) {
    // if the user is not a moderator AND
    // the status is not pending AND
    // the user is not the owner, then
    return;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I have understood already. My question is, how do I do a proper OR statement in my case? So I want to check if **either** $mod is set **OR** post author is currentuser etc

Comment: @HenrikPetterson `if ( ($mod)` instead of `if ( (!$mod)`

Comment: @George What are you talking about, so if it's a mod it should return? That's not what the user asked **at all**. _I want to return if the user is not a moderator OR if the user is not post author etc._

Comment: @insidesin I misunderstood what the OP wanted.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson, is this what you need? (updated answer)

Comment: @AlexTartan I doubt it, since you just provided a case where "condition AND condition" forces a return, whereas he wants OR... His original code in his question was closer. Not sure why it's not working for him though.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( (!$mod) && ( ($status != 'pending') && ($currentuser != $author) ) )
```

Because the user is not a mod it short circuits the second half of your if statement, by making it an and instead of or it will only return if both of the statements are true.

Another option is to do:

```
if(($mod) || ( ( ($status == 'pending') && ($current user == $author) ) ) {
    // do logic here
}
else {
    // user is not a mod and user is not the pending author
    return;
}
```

Comment: why the downvote? the answer fits ops question and explains what is wrong with the original code

Comment: Uhm. Because it does not fit the OP's question? Your centre `&&` should be an `||` as said in OP's post where he wants users whom aren't mods OR users whom aren't authors.

Comment: he wants to return when users are not mods or are not the author, if it is an or than it will always return if $mod is false, this is not what OP wants

Comment: What? You literally just contradicted yourself. You may need to look up how `||` works. If you're a moderator, you'll fail if you're not the post auther. If you're the post author you'll fail if you're not a moderator. That's the solution to his question, whether his question is logical or not is the question.

Comment: in OP's original post, if the user is not a moderator it will always return, in my original answer if op is not a moderator the first half will be true, for the entire if to be true the second part also needs to be true; this means that the program will only return if the user is not the moderator and the user is not the current user. In the OP's example the user is not a mod, so the first part is true, but because the user is the current user and stats is pending, the if statement is false on the whole and the program does not return, just like OP asked.

Comment: Yes. So you're essentially not fulfilling the OP's requests at all. His request was _"I want to return if the user is not a moderator OR if the user is not post author"._ In no way does that mean `!$mod && !$author` to return. The first part is true, then it returns... The if statement is true. `(true || false)` is equated to `true` not `false`... The OP asked for it to fail if the user was not a mod or not an author.

Comment: please refer to OP's example "So, in this example, the function should not return because $currentuser is $author and $status matches." ... OP is actually asking if the user is not a mod it must be the author, if the user is not the author the user must be a mod... he asked "What am I doing wrong." The or statement is not correct for his example, my answer tells him what he is doing wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: You really have no ability to write code do you? :| It's not returning because of that reason, it's returning because of not being a mod. i.e. one OR the other. Not hard logic to follow buddy. Your answer tells him nothing helpful.

Comment: notice how the highest ranked answer copied mine? He edited it after I posted my answer. Stop thinking like a computer and understand what the person is actually asking; you'll realize that an '||' is not the correct way to go.. there is a reason your answer is being downvoted

Comment: There's a simple explanation to that. You're both wrong. Feel free to be wrong with everyone else, you won't learn anything that way.